# How do I password protect a folder on macOS Catalina?

Tags: macos, finder, security, password, encryption

I have been attempting to password protect a folder on macOS Catalina. I did read through a couple of articles and previous answers and all of them talk about creating an encrypted disk image or password protected .zip folder. I need to have my folder such that, I double click on this normal regular looking folder and it prompts me for a password and if I type in the correct password it opens up the finder with the contents of that folder and/or I click on the folder again and it behaves like a regular folder. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can't. Return to your original references - or don't let other people know the password to your account.

Comment: Why does Linux distributions and Windows allow this but not macOS?

Comment: How is it achieved on Windows or nix?

Comment: You get the behavior you describe by using an encrypted DMG.

Comment: Very closely related https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16522/password-protect-folder-without-disk-images?rq=1 https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/272808/how-can-i-password-protect-files-in-macos?rq=1

Comment: Creating a “locked” folder is such a work around on Win10 that it’s better to either use an encrypted external disk (or flash drive), or a password protected zip folder.  Do the same on a Mac.